# NULLPOINT EXCEPTION ERROR during Simple Android app development

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, nullpointerexception, adt

i am trying to develop this simple app using Android ADT  and I got null point exception error. It is returning null point exception error at line 32 which is

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("your total is" + counter);


        }
    });
```

My whole java code is

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int counter;
Button add , subtract;
TextView display;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.badd1);
    subtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsub1);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("your total is" + counter);


        }
    });

    subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            display.setText("your total is" + counter);

        }
    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

MY xml CODE IS

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.newboston.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="your total is 0"
    android:textSize="45dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/badd1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="add one"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bsub1"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/badd1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/badd1"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="subtract one"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My logCat file is

```
03-25 23:10:29.219: D/AndroidRuntime(1211): Shutting down VM
03-25 23:10:29.229: W/dalvikvm(1211): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2b10ba8)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211): Process: com.example.newboston, PID: 1211
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity            ComponentInfo{com.example.newboston/com.example.newboston.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at      android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at com.example.newboston.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-25 23:10:29.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1211):     ... 11 more
03-25 23:10:36.449: I/Process(1211): Sending signal. PID: 1211 SIG: 9
```

Comment: @Brian Roach No, it's not.

Comment: Your code runs on a real device without changes when copied into a newly created Android project. You could try cleaning and rebuilding the project before running it.

Comment: @user3457567 Your code works. I just tested. Post your logcat.

Comment: @Onik When someone dumps their code here and says "I have an NPE", yes, it is. At least it's the nicer thing to do rather than just closing for "Unclear what you're asking". SO is not meant to be a free debugging service.

Comment: Your code works.Something else is wrong on your end

Comment: Post Your logcat here

Comment: I have kept my logcat here. Please reply.

Comment: Please if you can solve this..

Comment: Have you already cleaned and rebuilt your app? Sometimes editing layout XMLs makes the layout IDs in generated R.java and binary XML files go out of sync, and a rebuild fixes that.

Comment: Though `PlaceholderFragment` in `tools:context` attribute suggests the XML you posted isn't the same XML you're inflating as `R.layout.activity_main`

Comment: CAn you explain me more ? i am new to this. @laalto

Comment: @laalto thanks I got your point. My app is working

Answer (score 0):

If you're using more than one layout file (e.g layout-land, layout-sw360dp), make sure all elements you reference exist on all of them.

Comment: I posted my Logcat. Can you look at?